# remove duplicated tags jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this piece of code and i would like to look for duplicates
and if found i want to get alert that it already exists so users cant insert that word/tag. can some one please help

```
 <div id="tags">
<span>a</span> <span>b</span>
                <input type="text" value="" class="paste" id="search"  placeholder="Add a tag" />
              </div>
<script>
  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>",{text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value="";
      if (($('#tags span').length) >4) {
       $('#tags input').prop('disabled', true);
     }
    },

    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter|space (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout();
    }
  });

  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) $(this).remove();
     $('#tags input').prop('disabled', false);
  });

});

</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/nx7m5599/)

Comment: Loop through the spans with `.each()`, test if `$(this).text() == txt`.

Comment: `if(/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which))` should be `if(/^(188|13|32)$/.test(ev.which))`. You need the anchors, otherwise it will match things like `130` and `132`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a map of added tags, and before adding the tag, check if it exists:

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready
  // ::: TAGS BOX

  // added tags (mark 'a' and 'b' as already added)
  let tags = {
    'a': true, 
    'b': true
  };

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout: function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig, ''); // allowed characters

      if (txt) {

        if (tags[txt]) { // if the tag already exists show an error 
          console.log(txt + ' already exists');
        } else {
          $("<span/>", {
            text: txt.toLowerCase(),
            insertBefore: this
          });
          tags[txt] = true; // add the tag
        }
      }



      this.value = "";
      if (($('#tags span').length) > 4) {
        $('#tags input').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    },

    keyup: function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter|space (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if (/(188|13|32)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout();
    }
  });

  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    if (confirm("Remove " + $(this).text() + "?")) {
        $(this).remove();
        var text = $(this).text();
        tags[text] = false; // remove the tag
    }
    $('#tags input').prop('disabled', false);
  });

});
```

```css
#tags {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#tags>span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: #789;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
}

#tags>span:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#tags>span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "×";
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#tags>input {
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-container">
  <div id="tags">
    <span>a</span> <span>b</span>
    <input type="text" value="" class="paste" id="search" placeholder="Add a tag" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is pretty neat

Comment: dont really understand what the `let tag` does :(

Comment: what do you not understand: [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), or the logic of storing the added tags?